# Mangled OpenGL rendering on some platforms

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, hardware, glm-math

I have been experimenting with batched sprite rendering, and I've got a solution that works well on my desktop PC. However, trying it on my integrated Intel UHD 620 laptop I get the following performance warnings:

```
[21:42:03   error] OpenGL: API - Performance - Recompiling fragment shader for program 27
[21:42:03   error] OpenGL: API - Performance -   multisampled FBO 0->1
```

Presumably because of the source of these performance warnings, frames that take 1-2 milliseconds on my dedicated graphics card machine are about 100 milliseconds on my laptop.

Here is my renderer code:

```cpp
BatchedSpriteRenderer::BatchedSpriteRenderer(ResourceManager &resource_manager)
    : resource_manager(&resource_manager), 
      max_sprites(100000),
      vertex_array(std::make_unique<VertexArray>()),
      vertex_buffer(std::make_unique<VertexBuffer>())
{
    resource_manager.load_shader("batched_texture",
                                 "shaders/texture_batched.vert",
                                 "shaders/texture.frag");

    std::vector<unsigned int> sprite_indices;
    for (int i = 0; i < max_sprites; ++i)
    {
        unsigned int sprite_number = i * 4;
        sprite_indices.push_back(0 + sprite_number);
        sprite_indices.push_back(1 + sprite_number);
        sprite_indices.push_back(2 + sprite_number);
        sprite_indices.push_back(2 + sprite_number);
        sprite_indices.push_back(3 + sprite_number);
        sprite_indices.push_back(0 + sprite_number);
    }
    element_buffer = std::make_unique<ElementBuffer>(sprite_indices.data(), max_sprites * 6);

    VertexBufferLayout layout;
    layout.push<float>(2);
    layout.push<float>(2);
    layout.push<float>(4);
    vertex_array->add_buffer(*vertex_buffer, layout);
}

void BatchedSpriteRenderer::draw(const std::string &texture,
                                 const std::vector<glm::mat4> &transforms,
                                 const glm::mat4 &view)
{
    vertex_array->bind();

    auto shader = resource_manager->shader_store.get("batched_texture");
    shader->bind();

    std::vector<SpriteVertex> vertices;
    vertices.reserve(transforms.size() * 4);
    for (const auto &transform : transforms)
    {
        glm::vec4 transformed_position = transform * glm::vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        vertices.push_back({glm::vec2(transformed_position.x, transformed_position.y),
                            glm::vec2(0.0, 1.0),
                            glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)});
        transformed_position = transform * glm::vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        vertices.push_back({glm::vec2(transformed_position.x, transformed_position.y),
                            glm::vec2(0.0, 0.0),
                            glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)});
        transformed_position = transform * glm::vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        vertices.push_back({glm::vec2(transformed_position.x, transformed_position.y),
                            glm::vec2(1.0, 0.0),
                            glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)});
        transformed_position = transform * glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        vertices.push_back({glm::vec2(transformed_position.x, transformed_position.y),
                            glm::vec2(1.0, 1.0),
                            glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)});
    }
    vertex_buffer->add_data(vertices.data(),
                            sizeof(SpriteVertex) * vertices.size(),
                            GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    shader->set_uniform_mat4f("u_view", view);
    shader->set_uniform_1i("u_texture", 0);

    resource_manager->texture_store.get(texture)->bind();

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, transforms.size() * 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

Hopefully my abstractions should be fairly self explanatory. Each of the abstraction classes (`VertexArray`, `VertexBuffer`, `ElementBuffer`,`VertexBufferLayout`) manage the lifetime of their equivalent OpenGL object.

Here are the shaders being used:
`texture_batched.vert`

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0)in vec2 v_position; 
layout(location = 1)in vec2 v_tex_coord; 
layout(location = 2)in vec4 v_color; 

out vec4 color; 
out vec2 tex_coord; 

uniform mat4 u_view;

void main()
 {
    tex_coord = v_tex_coord;
    gl_Position = u_view * vec4(v_position, 0.0, 1.0);
    color = v_color;
}
```

`texture.frag`

```
#version 430 core

in vec4 color; 
in vec2 tex_coord; 

out vec4 frag_color; 

uniform sampler2D u_texture; 

void main()
 {
    frag_color = texture(u_texture, tex_coord);
    frag_color *= color;
}
```

What's causing these performance issues, and how can I fix them?

EDIT: I completely forgot to mention that the actual image rendered with this is completely messed up, I'll try and grab a screenshot of it working correctly when I get to my desktop PC, but here's what the broken version looks like:
[image: Mangled rendering]

It should be a neat grid of 200x200 white circles.

EDIT 2: I tried it on another computer, this time with a GTX 1050 Ti, and it is also broken. No error messages or warnings this time. The warning may have been unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being unrelated to OpenGL, as far as I can see.

In the draw function, I create a vector called `vertices`, then put all the vertices in it. For some reason, when I recreate that vector every frame the following `push_back` calls aren't properly adding to the vector. The members of the `SpriteVertex` structs were getting mixed up. As such, instead of the correct layout:

```
pos tex_coord color
pos tex_coord color
pos tex_coord color
pos tex_coord color
```

It was being filled in the following layout:

```
pos tex_coord color
tex_coord pos color
tex_coord pos color
tex_coord pos color
```

Or something to that effect, at least.

I changed it so that the `vertices` vector is a member of the `BatchedSpriteRenderer` class, reserving space for the maximum possible number of vertices.

```cpp
void BatchedSpriteRenderer::draw(const std::string &texture,
                                 const std::vector<glm::mat4> &transforms,
                                 const glm::mat4 &view)
{
    vertex_array->bind();

    auto shader = resource_manager->shader_store.get("batched_texture");
    shader->bind();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < transforms.size(); ++i)
    {
        const auto &transform = transforms[i];

        glm::vec4 transformed_position = transform * glm::vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        vertices[i * 4] = {glm::vec2(transformed_position.x,
                                     transformed_position.y),
                           glm::vec2(0.0, 1.0),
                           glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)};

        transformed_position = transform * glm::vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        vertices[i * 4 + 1] = {glm::vec2(transformed_position.x,
                                         transformed_position.y),
                               glm::vec2(0.0, 0.0),
                               glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)};

        transformed_position = transform * glm::vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        vertices[i * 4 + 2] = {glm::vec2(transformed_position.x,
                                         transformed_position.y),
                               glm::vec2(1.0, 0.0),
                               glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)};

        transformed_position = transform * glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        vertices[i * 4 + 3] = {glm::vec2(transformed_position.x,
                                         transformed_position.y),
                               glm::vec2(1.0, 1.0),
                               glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)};
    }

    vertex_buffer->add_data(vertices.data(),
                            sizeof(SpriteVertex) * (transforms.size() * 4),
                            GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    shader->set_uniform_mat4f("u_view", view);
    shader->set_uniform_1i("u_texture", 0);

    resource_manager->texture_store.get(texture)->bind();

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, transforms.size() * 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```